# How can I loop over a nested dictionary to return a string?

Tags: swift

I have a nested dictionary like this:

```
let dictionary: [String: [String:String]?]? = [
  "Some Value A":nil,
  "Some Value B":nil,
  "Some Value C":nil,
]
```

And I have a function like this that should return a string but I am confused with the optional binding logic.

```
func name(dictonary: [String: [String : String]?]?, info: String) -> String {
        var tempString = ""
            for (a, b) in ((dictonary[info])!)! {
                tempString = tempString + "\n" + "\(a), population: \(b)"
            }
        return tempString
    }
```

Dont mind the wrong variable names...
Thanks :p

Comment: Ups the first parameter in the function is also an optional Dictionary like the 'dictionary' constant.

Comment: Instead of posting a comment, [edit] your question as needed.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first time using stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lots of optionals that need to be dealt with properly. The first thing you need to do is thoroughly read everything in the [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) book regarding optionals.

Then the following will make more sense:

```
func name(dictonary: [String: [String : String]?]?, info: String) -> String {
    var tempString = ""
    if let dictionary = dictionary, let innerDict = dictionary[info] {
        for (key, value) in innerDict {
            tempString += "\n" + "\(key), population: \(value)"
        }
    }

    return tempString
}
```

The key is to safely unwrap the optionals. Never (at least until you really know what you are doing) force-unwrap (use the `!` operator).

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget that you should accept answers that best answer your questions.